# Bootstrap: how to vertically align two buttons, at the start and the end of a title?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I'm using bootstrap 3 modals, the design I've been asked to do is

[image]

Notice how the graphic designer placed a button vertically aligned with the start of the text and another vertically aligned with the end of the text.

My code is

```
<div class="fr-popup-title">
<div class="modal-title">
<div class="row fr-title-popup-margin">
<?php echo $question_title; ?>
</div>
<div class="row">
<?php echo $you_know; ?>
</div>
<div class="row">
<?php echo $migrant; ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-4 pl col-md-push-2">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning modal-fr-btn yes-fr-popup" data-dismiss="modal">
<?php echo $yes; ?>
</button>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-4 btn-col pr col-md-push-3">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning modal-fr-btn close-fr-popup" data-dismiss="modal">
<?php echo $no; ?>
</button>
</div>
</div>
```

I get what I want but not the alignment I want, if I add some margins, it will break on another screen, what's the best way to solve it?

Please note that I tried inserting all my code as a snippet and it made more mess than the real deal, don't use the snippet as a reference, my code in a browser is way better, and don't worry about my classes, they seem like a lot but all of them are useless, they are nothing but a failed attempt at aligning.

The one without snippet is the same but easier to read.

```js
$(window).on('load', function () {
$('#francepopup').modal('show');
    });
```

```css
    .fr-title-popup-margin {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .fr-popup-title {
        font-size: 24px;
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        color: #008cc0;
        font-weight: 800;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .modal-fr-btn {
        border-radius: 40px;
        height: 25px;
        width: 80px;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        color: white;
        font-weight: 800;
    }

    .dont {
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 6px;
    }

    .fr-flags {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .fr-text {
        margin: 0 auto 0 3px
    }

    @media (min-width: 992px) {
        .modal-dialog {
            width: 30%;
        }
    }

    @media (max-width: 991px) {
        .pr {
            float: right;
        }

        .pl {
            float: left;
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<body>
<div class="modal fade" id="francepopup" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <button type="button" class="close close-fr-popup" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

            <div class="fr-popup-title">
                <div class="modal-title">
                    <div class="row fr-title-popup-margin">
                        Are you or is someone
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                       you know
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        a migrant in France?
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 pl col-md-push-2">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning modal-fr-btn yes-fr-popup" data-dismiss="modal">
                            Yes
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-4 btn-col pr col-md-push-3">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning modal-fr-btn close-fr-popup" data-dismiss="modal">
                            No
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: please add your css (other than boostrap) - it's the main concern in this question. Consider making a snippet.

Comment: @RachelGallen done that but don't use the snippet as a reference, it's way more messy than what my code looks like in a real browser, I'm just missing few margins.

Comment: Have you ever used [flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)?

Comment: @Jay intentionally no, meaning I have never stumbled upon a problem and said "flexbox is the only way to implement it".  Because in my mind, flexbox is just another tool and I don't know if it's responsive, at least bootstrap is. What you're saying is the problem is easy to solve in flexbox?

Comment: it's not the only way, but it is responsive and I find it easier for controlling layout.

Comment: @Jay Could you post an answer using flexbox? I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i simply edited your code and i hope it is what you really needed :)

```js
$(window).on('load', function () {
$('#francepopup').modal('show');
    });
```

```css
 .fr-title-popup-margin {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .fr-popup-title {
        font-size: 23px;
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        color: #008cc0;
        font-weight: 800;
        /*text-align: center;*/
    }

    .modal-fr-btn {
        border-radius: 40px !important;
        /*height: 25px;*/
        width: 80px;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        color: white;
        font-weight: 800;
    }

    .dont {
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 6px;
    }

    .fr-flags {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .fr-text {
        margin: 0 auto 0 3px
    }

    @media (min-width: 992px) {
        .modal-dialog {
            width: 30%;
        }
    }

    @media (max-width: 991px) {
        .pr {
            float: right;
        }

        .pl {
            float: left;
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<body>
<div class="modal fade" id="francepopup" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <button type="button" class="close close-fr-popup" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

            <div class="fr-popup-title">
                
                <div class="modal-title">
                  <div style="display:flex">
                    <div style="max-width:25.33333333%; flex: 0 0 25.33333333%;"></div>
                    <div style="max-width:49.33333333%; text-align:center">
                      Are you or is someone <br/>
                      you know <br/>
                      a migrant in france?
                    </div>
                    <div style="max-width:25.33333333%; flex: 0 0 25.33333333%;"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div style="display:flex">
                  <div style="max-width:25.33333333%; flex: 0 0 25.33333333%;"></div>
                  <div style="max-width:49.33333333%; flex: 0 0 49.33333333%">
                  <button type="button" style="float:left; width:115px; height:40px; font-size:18px" class="btn btn-warning modal-fr-btn yes-fr-popup" data-dismiss="modal">
                      Yes
                    </button>
                    
                    <button type="button" style="float:right;width:115px; height:40px; font-size:18px" class="btn btn-warning modal-fr-btn close-fr-popup" data-dismiss="modal">
                      No
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div style="max-width:25.33333333%; flex: 0 0 25.33333333%;"></div>
                 
              </div>
              <br/>
               <div style="display:flex">
                    <div style="max-width:25.33333333%; flex: 0 0 25.33333333%;"></div>
                    <div style="max-width:49.33333333%; flex: 0 0 49.33333333%; text-align:right; margin-top:-15px">
                        (Please dont ask  <br/> me this again)
                    </div>
                    <div style="max-width:25.33333333%; flex: 0 0 25.33333333%;"></div>
              </div>
             
          </div>

      </div>

  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: It works on slightly smaller screens but not 22 inches (my screen), it looks like this https://imgur.com/YHhnZBH

Comment: i already did it for desktop size but you can add some media queries on it to fit in smaller screen sizes